# codesandbox.io unable to point to anything expcet "index.html"

Tags: javascript, html, codesandbox

Trying to setup a vanilla JS on `codesandbox.io`, when I change the name of the `index` file, the app no longer can see the HTML at all and throws an error. I must be missing something here, why can I not change the name?
In the link [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/great-chaplygin-9ftv4), I have a very basic reproduction of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html page can be loaded by navigating to it in the mini browser:

[image]

When sharing the sandbox a default url can be configured:
[image]

By choosing other options:
[image]

and entering the url:
[image]

and then sharing it:
[image]

The result:
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-morning-j9fvl?fontsize=14&initialpath=notIndex.html

Comment: This works and yet is not ideal (obviously not your doing)

Comment: Yea it is really hard to find, but it works :) @Michael

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no way to change the name entry point. It seems that the "index" name is hardcoded in the service code.

Comment: There is a way, check the other answer :)